# I need regex to validate a pattern

Tags: regex, barcode

I need regex to validate a pattern,
pattern can be combination of following list,

- **`yyyy`** : current year
- **`yy`**  : last 2 digits of current year
- **`MM`**  : current month
- **`dd`**  : current day
- **`HH`**  : current hour
- **`mm`**  : current minute
- **`ss`**  : current second
- **`fff`** : current milisecond
- **`ff`**  : current 1/100th of second
- **`R`**   : random digits

### Rules

Minimum 16 and maximum 20 characters can be allowed.

We should be able to add fix characters only in capitals(e.g. '`yyyyAAddmmss`' here `AA` is fix value)

We should escape a fix character(e.g. `\R`, then `R` is not replaced)

Only `HMR` characters should be allowed to escape like '`\H`' or '`\M`' or '`\R`' as this characters are in the pattern.

Pattern should contains minimum 4 random digits (e.g. `yyRMMRddRHHRmmRss`)

It should allow digits `0-9`

It should not allow special characters.

### Example of such valid pattern

```
yyyyMMddHHmmssff
yyyyMMddHHmmssffR
AByyyyMMddHHmmssRRRR
AByyyy\RMMddHHRRmmRR
\Myy\HMMdd\RRHHmmss99RR
```

Comment: What did you try and what didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

What is **ff**? Is it `current-milliseconds/100` or `current-seconds/100`?

If It's `current-milliseconds/100` [use this regex](https://regex101.com/r/LPqf1F/1)

`\d{2}(\d{2})(\w{3})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{13})(\d{11}.\d{2})(\d+)`

Comment: It will be used like,

DateTime dateValue = new DateTime(2008, 7, 16, 8, 32, 45, 180); 

Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("fff")); 

Console.WriteLine(dateValue.ToString("ff")); 


https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-display-milliseconds-in-date-and-time-values

Answer (score 0):

> Pattern should contains minimum 4 random digits (e.g. `yyRMMRddRHHRmmRss`)

You are asking for something that may not yield one unique match.

For example, the pattern `20110221318763521` could be matched in many ways:

```
20110221318323521
yyRMMRddRHHRmmRss => 20-10-21 18:23:21
yyMMRRddRHHRmmRss => 20-11-21 18:23:21
yyRRMMddRHHRmmRss => 20-02-21 18:23:21
yyRMMRddRHHmmRssR => 20-10-21 18:32:52
...
```